# Need help in showing that $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ is a principal ideal ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I'm asked to show that $\mathbb{Z}_m$ (the integers mod $m$) is a principal ideal ring for every $m > 0$

I see that it is the same discussion used in verifying that $\mathbb{Z}$ (the set of all integers) is.

Can anybody help me in writing a correct solution?

Comment: Notice that $\phi: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ defined by $a \mapsto a+n\mathbb Z$ is actually a surjective homomorphism, which says that that the latter is the homomorphic image of $\mathbb Z$. So in some sense this question is asking " do generic homomorphisms preserve the property of being a PID?" 
The answer is yes.
the reverse is not true: "if $\phi: A  \to B$ is a surjective homomorphism with $B$ a PID, is $A$ is a principal ideal domain?" consider the projection $\mathrm{Frac A} \to A$, where $A$ is not a PID.

Answer (score 2):

Use that $\Bbb Z_m$ is a quotient of $\Bbb Z$. In general, the residues of the generators of an ideal generate the image of the ideal in the quotient.

Comment: may u give me some details for the steps of the solution ?

Comment: @benh if you're still around and you want to give a more detailed answer, there's a 100 point bounty on this question.

Answer (score 2):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is more correctly denoted $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, that is the quotient ring of $\mathbb{Z}$ modulo the ideal $m\mathbb{Z}$. The ring $\mathbb{Z}$ is known to be a principal ideal domain (even Euclidean).

We can prove a more general result.

> **Theorem.** *Let $f\colon A\to B$ be surjective homomorphism of commutative rings. If $A$ is a principal ideal ring, then $B$ is a principal ideal ring.*

*Proof.* Let $I$ be an ideal of $B$. Consider
$$
f^{\gets}(I)=\{a\in A:f(a)\in I\}
$$
It's easy to prove that $f^{\gets}(I)$ is an ideal of $A$. Therefore there exists $a\in A$ such that $f^{\gets}(I)=(a)$.

Consider $b=f(a)$; then $I=(b)$. Indeed, $b=f(a)\in I$ by definition, so $(b)\subseteq I$.

Conversely, if $y\in I$, then $y=f(x)$, for some $x\in A$ (here we use surjectivity of $f$). By definition, $x\in f^{\gets}(I)=(a)$, so $x=az$ for some $z\in A$. Hence
$$
y=f(x)=f(az)=f(a)f(z)=bf(z)\in (b)
$$
Therefore $I\subseteq (b)$. QED

Now apply the theorem to the canonical homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Comment: that notation is very strange $f^{\leftarrow}(I)$. Why not just use the inverse? On the other hand, this is pretty much the way I wound up proving it myself.

Comment: Since $f$ is surjective, it may not have an inverse. The notation $f^{\gets}$ is a nice notation for the pullback, or preimage, of an element or a set without confusing that with implying $f$ has an honest-to-goodness inverse.

Comment: @ALannister I prefer it to $f^{-1}(I)$, which can be a problem for beginners, who often mistake the symbol to mean that $f$ is invertible. I chose this technique of proof because this generality helps in leaving aside details which are mostly irrelevant (like the gcd or the correspondence theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID.

And also note that there is an inclusion preserving bijection between the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ and ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ which contain the ideal $m\mathbb{Z}$.

So any ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ looks like $I/m\mathbb{Z}$ where I is an ideal containing the ideal $m\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Since I is generated by a single element, so is $I/m\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Hence $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is a principle ideal ring.

explanation for the missing part

Let $\phi:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{m} $ where $\phi(x) = x+m\mathbb{Z}$ for all x in $\mathbb{Z}$. This is a surjective ring homomorphism.

Note that inverse image of an ideal is an ideal for a ring homomorphism and image of an ideal is an ideal for a surjective ring homomorphism.

So if J is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$, then $\phi^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ which contains the ideal $m\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $I=\phi^{-1}(J)$ , then I contains $m\mathbb{Z}$ since 0+$m\mathbb{Z}$ is in J.

then $\phi(I)=J=I/m\mathbb{Z}$.

this proves the surjection between the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ and the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ which contain the ideal $m\mathbb{Z}$.

Even though inclusion preserving is true, it is not needed for proving your result.

Since I is a ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $I=(k)$ for some integer k.

then ideal $(m)\subseteq (k)$. Then k divides m.

So I is the ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by divisors of m.

Comment: what is this inclusion preserving bijection between the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ and the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ of which you speak? Also, before you can even use this, don't you need to show that all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ are of the form $m\mathbb{Z}$? And if so, how would you go about doing that?

Comment: Please flush out all of your answer, so that it is complete!

Comment: No I am not saying that ideals of  $\mathbb{Z}_m$ are of the form $m\mathbb{Z}$, they are of the form  $I/m\mathbb{Z}$ where I is an ideal containing the ideal $m\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.                                    Well the inclusion preserving bijection map between the sets which I am using is due to the correspondence theorem for ideals of ring and its quotient ring, which can be proved using First isomorphism theorem for rings.

Comment: probably you are trying to prove that any ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $k\mathbb{Z}$ where k is an integer.

Comment: @SivaKumar no I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ is a principal ideal ring. But I want to make sure that all the t's are crossed and the i's are dotted.

Comment: @SivaKumar also I am not familiar with the correspondence theorem. Could you explicitly state what this bijection is, please?

Comment: @SivaKumar are you using one of the Isomorphism Theorems, perhaps?

Comment: Yes I am using 3rd Isomorphism theorem or Lattice isomorphism theorem

Comment: @SivaKumar what exactly do these ideals $\phi^{-1}(J)$ which are ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ containing the ideal $m \mathbb{Z}$ look like?

Answer (score 1):

To start, I want to set up some notation so that my answer doesn't look terribly cluttered. Let $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ be denoted as $A$, and the ideal generated by an integer $k$ as $(k)$. Similarly, the ideal generated by $n$ and $k$ will be $(n,k)$. Note that $A=(1)$.

Now, to find the ideals of $A$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, we'll investigate the possible forms an ideal $I\subseteq A$ may have. We note the following property of ideals:

> Since by definition of ideals, $kn\in I$ whenever $k\in A$ and $n\in I$, then it follows that $kI = \{kn:k\in A, n\in I\} = I$.

Suppose that $n\in I$. This tells us that all multiples of $n$ must also be in $I$, and hence $(n)$ is an ideal of $A$. Furthermore, if $\gcd(n,m)=1$ then $n$ is invertible in $A$. Then since $n^{-1}(n)=(n)$, this implies that $1\in(n)$, so $(n)=(1)=A$, so $(n)$ is not a proper ideal. Since this is true for any ideal containing $n$, we may assume that any proper ideal in $A$ contains no invertible elements (also called units).

Now, can there be other ideals? To investigate this, consider two integers, $n$ and $k$, such that $n\notin(k)$ and $k\notin(n)$. Let $\gcd(n,k)=d$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Euclidean domain, there are integers $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $an+bk=d$. Furthermore, this equality still holds in $A$ when we replace $a$ and $b$ with their remainder modulo $m$. This implies that $(n,k)=(d)$, since every element is a multiple of $d$.

Therefore, any proper ideal of $A$ generated by two elements is also generated by a single element, and hence is principal. This shows that $A$ is a Principal Ideal Domain.

Comment: The existence of integers $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $an+bk=d$, that's Bezout's Identity, right?

Comment: Yes, though it's important to note that I am not assuming Bezout's identity holds for $A$ -- only that it holds for $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: right, although you could just convert the elements of $A$ to elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ by identifying them with some $0\leq x \leq n-1$, using Bezout's identity on the converted form and then converting it back to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

Comment: Exactly! Once you find the expression in $\mathbb{Z}$, you can just pass it through to $A$.